# Powershell ISE doesnt return mongo connection to user, So I cant type any command there

Tags: mongodb, powershell, windows-10, powershell-ise

I am trying to connect to mongo DB with window's powershell ISE. It connects and shows up in the tab where I have run mongod, but when in the tab where i have run mongo command, it doesnt give back the cursor where I can type my commands.
P.S - Its working fine in powershell, seems like only powershell ISE is being buggy.

[image]
Nowhere I can type in here.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this post](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9310) Mongo currently only support cmd.exe and powershell.exe.

Comment: I faced the same issue. "mongo" command worked on Powershell.exe but not working on "Powershell ISE".